# Destructuring by name of argument from object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, destructuring, eslint-config-airbnb

I use ESLint with Airbnb config. I must destruct variable from the state in my setText function because I have ESLint error: "Must use destructing state assignment (react/destructuring-assignment)". Is it possible to destruct by name of the argument from the state object?

```
setText = (lang, key, e) => {
  // I must destruct variable by name of lang argument from state object here
  this.setState({
    [lang]: {
      ...this.state[lang],  // ESLint destructuring-assignment error is here
      [key]: e.target.value,
    },
  });
};
```

Examples of using the function with different inputs:

```
<input
  type="text"
  value={this.state.en.shortDescription}
  onChange={e => this.setText('en', 'shortDescription', e)}
/>
```

or

```
<input
  type="text"
  value={this.state.de.title}
  onChange={e => this.setText('de', 'title', e)}
/>
```

My .eslintrc file:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: how exactly error looks? what if `this.state[lang]` is `undefined`? then you will get error because of spread operator with `undefined`

Comment: Your code works just fine for me,

Comment: What specifically is the error? This is an ESLint error? If it's set to `always` wouldn't you need to pull out `this.state[lang]`?

Comment: @KevinB This isn't a code functionality question, this is an ESLint question.

Comment: @skyboyer This isn't a code functionality question, this is an ESLint question.

Comment: and? No error was provided. My eslint doesn't throw one. ergo, not a real problem

Comment: I'd rather expect error about referring `this.state` in `.setState`

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, it's ESLint error. I use this function for several different inputs

Comment: like this  
this.setText('en', 'title', e); or this  
this.setText('de', 'shortDescription', e);

Comment: Such an assignment used to only be allowed at the end: `[lang]: {
      [key]: e.target.value,
     ...this.state[lang]
    },` I'm willing to be that is the cause of the error.

Comment: @TinyGiant no, I must destruct variable by name of lang argument from state object before this.setState

Comment: @Vlad Are you asking for `const {state: {[lang]: x}} = this, {target: {value}} = e; this.setState({[lang]: {...x, [key]: value }});`?

Comment: @Vlad please say what the actual error is (copy paste it) in your post. If this is just an ESLint issue then the solution is a pretty straight forward "tell your ESlint config to _ignore_ that error". AirBnB's ESlint config is not guaranteed to fit your own needs, so [write an eslint config that extends the AirBnB config](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring), and override the setting for the specific thing it's flagging as "an error" even though it's perfectly fine according to you.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, it worked for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: If that is what your linter wants, it looks like a mistake to use this linter setting. That is horrible code.

Comment: @Bergi What should I do? Maybe the better solution is to add this part of the code to the exception?

Comment: Start by editing your question to include the actual linter message you get and the linter setting that you use, so that we can a) reproduce the problem and b) suggest how to change your settings

Comment: @Bergi ok, done.

Comment: @KevinB The error was provided, otherwise I couldn’t have looked it up :) And remember why I ended up turning it off; for larger functions it mostly makes sense, but when using interpolation like this, or for short functions, it ends up being worse.

Comment: Another problem is that you shoudn't use `this.state` together with `setState`. Use updater function.

Comment: after looking into [plugin's description](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md) I guess eslint rather complains about having `e.target.value` instead of destructuring it in function's arguments like `setText = (lang, key, {target: {value}}) => ...`
why next line has been mentioned then? I don't know actually. But this way it makes sense.